# Two sequences of real numbers $c(n)$ and $b(n)$ defined by $b(1)=c(1)$ and $bn=c(n)-c(n-1)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $(b_n)$ be defined by: $b_1 = c_1$ and $b_n = c_n - c_{n-1}$ if $n \geq 2$. Prove that the sequence $(c_n)$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_n b_n$ converges.

I have no idea how to start this question. I understand that for $b_n$ to converge we need it to to be bounded above, so for example we can have $\dfrac{1}{n}$ or even $(0, 0, \dotsc)$, then I thought we can say that $c_n$ converges since it would be a subsequence, and Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem states that for any bounded sequence of reals there exists a subsequence which converges to $\mathbb{R}$. This doesn't sound very thorough, though, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you should write it becuase its hardly visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)Let's prove that  $ \sum {b_n}$ converges. You suppose that $c_n$ converge, so lets $S_j= \sum_{k=1}^j b_k=c_1+\sum_{k=2}^j c_k-c_{k-1}=c_j$. So $\lim\nolimits_{j \to \infty}S_j=\lim\nolimits_{j \to \infty}c_j$, and so you have that $ \sum {b_n}$ converges.

You can do the other implication with the same method.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\nolimits_n b_n &= b_n + b_{n-1} + \dotsb + b_1 \\
&= c_n - c_{n-1} + c_{n-1} - c_{n-2} + \dotsb + c_2 - c_1 + c_1 \\&= c_n
\end{align}$$

So if $\sum_n b_n$ converges, it is in fact the same thing as saying $c_n$ converges, and vice versa.